# Rearrange full name to surname being displayed first in listbox

Tags: c#, sql

I have a field in my database table called Name which stores a users full name

For example:-

> Leona Hill

I want to display a list of names in listbox being populated from sql datasource to show surname first and then forename after surname is this possible.

For example:-

> Hill Leona

Comment: Can FirstName or LastName span multiple words ?

Comment: So what exactly part is causing troubles to you? Getting data from DB, reformatting data, binding to listbox? What have you tried and what problem have you faced? Try to be more specific....

Comment: Names can be weird. What it the current and the desired order for, say, `Charles de Batz-Castelmore d'Artagnan`?

Comment: If it is a simple reverse operation where every part is strictly one word at max, then you can do this:   `string reversed = String.Join(" ", FullName.Split(' ').Reverse())`

Comment: Try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ejfrEM)

Comment: We can get data from the database and display it in the listbox but its shows as Leona Hill whereas we want it to be displayed as Hill Leona.  Is there a way to do this in sql query designer?